# Can i get a count of how many times Rxjava 2 all has already retried?

Tags: android, rx-java

Is there a doOnRetry or some way to get number of retries attempted?

Comment: There is a [retry](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#retry-io.reactivex.functions.BiPredicate-) overload that provides the retry count.

Comment: How does this Predicate get the retry count? For example if retry count is 1 show a Loading.. icon, if 2 show a network is retrying view, etc

Comment: Could you use `doOnSubscribe` to increment a counter?

Comment: how do i increment a not-final variable outside an anonymous inner function?

Comment: Please provide code what you have and intend to do.